# Using the PayPalAPIInterfaceService, can I lookup the Payment Profile ID using a Transaction ID?

Tags: api, paypal

I'm using PayPal's PayPalAPIInterfaceService and I see that I can pass TransactionSearch a Payment Profile ID and it will pull back all Payment Transactions but is there a way to take a Payment Transaction ID and get back the associated Payment Profile ID?

We're trying to reconcile monthly Transactions and while the Transaction records returned from TransactionSearch indicate they're Recurring Payments, they don't seem to give the assocaited Payment Profile ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IPN and having all the transaction information written to your database, you could just query your own database for this information.  If you are not using IPN, you could set it up and use it for transactions and profiles going forward.